# OneDrive Api GET METHOD (No One Can Fix It :S)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, onedrive

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=*********&scope=onedrive.readwrite&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://localhost:54540/Home/Dashboard',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: true,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

I am getting the following Error
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:54540' is therefore not allowed access.

I know its about CORS but i cant find any simple solution.

Comment: https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp

Comment: BY using your method now i am getting this error `because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use ajax to get an auth token from the login server. Since this process may involve requiring the user of your app to log in or consent to giving your app access to their data, you need to navigate to that URL in the browser itself.

Here's [more info about using oauth with OneDrive](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm). You should also take a look at the [javascript sample app](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-explorer-js) and see how it works in practice.